# Write if else condition based on test execution order in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute a code in which I am stuck and landed in a question whether we can write an if else condition in java with respect to the execution order or priority number in TestNG.

What I wanted to do is,

```
if(TestNGprioritynum==1){
    HSSFSheet s = newsheet(sheetnum);
}

if(TestNGprioritynum==2){
    HSSFSheet s = newsheet(sheetnum1);
}
```

`TestNGprioritynum` is not a class or any code. It is just an illustration of what I want to do. Is there any library inside TestNG or any third party tool or anything in Java which I can use to decide actions on condition with respect to priority of TestNG test cases? Any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the priority of the test method being run using the `ITestResult` object in a method annotated with `@BeforeMethod`. Then depending on the priority, set an attribute which could be used in the actual test method.

```java
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(ITestContext ctx, ITestResult res) {
    ITestNGMethod method = res.getMethod();
    int num = (method.getPriority() == 1) ? sheetNum : sheetNum1;
    ctx.setAttribute("sheetnum", num);
}

@Test(priority = 1) {
public void yourTest(ITestContext ctx) {
    HSSFSheet s = newsheet((int) ctx.getAttribute("sheetnum");
}
```